# What happens to quality of breast milk when twins of two different sexes are born?

Tags: reproduction, mammals, nutrition, twins, milk

It says [here](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/boys-and-girls-may-get-different-breast-milk/#:%7E:text=In%20humans%20and%20other%20mammals,conditions%20are%20good%20or%20bad.&text=The%20new%20study%20also%20follows,dense%20milk%20for%20male%20infants.) in Scientific American

> Mother's milk may be the first food, but it is not created equal. In
> humans and other mammals, researchers have found that milk composition
> changes depending on the infant's gender and on whether conditions are
> good or bad. Understanding those differences can give scientists
> insights into human evolution.
>
> Researchers at Michigan State University and other institutions found
> that among 72 mothers in rural Kenya, women with sons generally gave
> richer milk (2.8 percent fat compared with 0.6 percent for daughters).

Now I'm curious as to what happens when fraternal twins of different genders are born?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. Please take the [tour] and consult the [help] starting with [ask] for details about what is expected on this site and then [edit] accordingly. I've made some minor edits, but I encourage you to think about whether the last paragraph adds anything to your question — my recommendation would be to delete since it not based on scientific evidence. It would also help if you could indicate where you've looked for answers to this specific question.

Comment: @trondhansen is Scientific American not a reliable source? Also it's Kenyan women, I don't know which ethnicity is being reffered in Wikipedia. Does Ethnicity influence nutritional content? Economic status can also influence it.

Comment: @MrGreenGold i removed my comment because the article in the scientific american does not have a reliable source and Marissa is a freelance science journalist not a scientist.it is unlikely that the mother produces milk with only 0.6% fat if the baby is a girl and the same mother produces milk with 2.8% fat if the baby is a boy,it is an increase of 5x the fat content(normal fat content in mothersmilk is 4.2%).